# How can I fallback claim value in Azure custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've created a custom policy that allows authentication using both personal Microsoft accounts and Work accounts (O365) using the OpenID Connect (using the https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration config).

My application expects the "signInNames.emailAddress" claim to be provided, however in certain circumstances this claim is not provided (for example, if the user has no O365 mailbox).

In these cases I want to fallback to the preferred_username claim.  How can I conditionally move this value into the "signInNames.emailAddress" claim in this scenario within the policy?  Unfortunately I have no control over the claims the application is expecting, so this must be done within the policy.